# Autosize in PowerPoint tables office 2010

Tags: powerpoint, autosize

I would appreciate some help with this issue. How can I use the autosize property in a table in powerpoint? Office 2010. I use this code, which seems logic (and founded in internet) and it's not working.

```
ppPres.Slides(NumSlide).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1,3).Shape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
```

Thanks in advance
Albert

Comment: There are a few oddities to cells (and the associated shapes/textframes) within tables. This is probably one, and it makes sense because you can't have a single cell getting larger/smaller within a row or column that remains fixed in height/width.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant the text, not the cell. I want that the text adapts to the cell, not viceversa.

Comment: Same problem, really; table cell text has slightly different properties from regular text. If you create a table manually in PPT, add text, select it and then try to format it, you'll find that the text auto-fit options are all grayed out/inaccessible.